# disable some dropdown select controls when a user clicks on a checkbox

Tags: jquery, combobox

i have a time dropdown that shows hour in one select, minutes in another and AM/PM in a third.  I have a checkbox that says "All day"

i want it so when the user checks on "All day" all of the select dropdowns become disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble with checkboxes is principally getting them to work right in IE6, since the `change` event fires at all manner of unhelpful times.

Let's start with the function to do the disabling:

```
function onCheckChange() {
  if ($("#all-day-checkbox").is(':checked'))
    $("select").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  else
    $("select").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Note that I here use just `select` which is almost certainly more broad than you'd want, but `select.some-class-to-identify-the-hours-and-minutes-and-seconds-dropdowns` would work just as well.

Note also that the function figures out itself whether the box is checked, making it idempotent: it's safe to call repeatedly during the process of checking a box.

Now we just need to bind that function to a few different events:

```
$("#all-day-checkbox").click(onCheckChange).change(onCheckChange);
$("label[for=all-day-checkbox]").click(onCheckChange);
```

Comment: @oo - you will need to put at least the bind code into the (document).ready, you can put the onCheckChange function into it, but that's not necessary.

Comment: what is the label second line at the bottom for?

Comment: select works fine but when i change it to select.hours or select.time it stops working. any suggestions?

Comment: The label click is important in the world of IE so your event will trigger if the user clicks the label instead of the checkbox, since the click event is what will fire first.  `select.hours` will work fine as long as that `select` box has `class="hours"`  I'd suggest giving them all `class="time-picker"` (or something similar), and then you can use `select.time-picker` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#allday').toggle(
    function(){
        $('#hour, #minutes, #am-pm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
    function(){
        $('#hour, #minutes, #am-pm').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#Hour, #Minute, #Period').attr('disabled', this.checked);    
});
```

Comment: I don't think onchange can be used on checkboxes. At least this didn't work when I tested it. Or if it can be used, I don't know that it would work here, since the "value" of the checkbox isn't technically changing.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that you could use onchange on anything but a select box. But I suppose that's reasonable considering the jQuery docs say that it's when a control changes value. Still a little confusing in this instance. Also, your code is only one-way. What if the user de-selects #checkbox?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief you can set disabled equal to a Boolean value.

Comment: Whoops, nvm. Guess you covered that with the this.checked bool. :p